# Check iframe content for a specific text

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an iFrame with a src to a third party site. I managed to display that iframe sanitizing the URL.

The only way I have to find out if the user's process was completed, is by a text on this third party page that say "Congratulations. Your policy is effective now", so I thought about checking the iFrame content looking for that phrase.

I did the following code to check for that specific string, every 3 seconds, but the iContent variable is not retrieving any value:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    const source = interval(3000);
    this.subscription = source.subscribe(val => {
      var iContent = document.getElementById("MyIframe").innerHTML.toString()
      if (iContent.includes("Congratulations. Your policy is effective now")) {
        alert("It worked")
      }
    }
    );
  }
```

Should I approach this from a different angle?

Thanks.

ADDITIONAL NOTE:

I am creating the iframe and passing a parameter from the .ts file like this:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.style.width = "100%";
        iframe.style.height = "1200px";
        iframe.name = "MyIframe";
        iframe.id = "MyIframe";
        var html = '<body style="display=none;" onload="document.allState.submit()"><form name="allState" method="POST" action="' + this.ContinuationURL + '"><input type="text" id="token" name="token" value="' + this.MemberAccessToken + '"><button type="submit">submit</button></form></body>';
        iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Which redirects to the provider's page.

Comment: What's the purpose of 'val' inside your subscribe method?, I see you are not using it...Wouldn't be better to build the HTML inside a template html script instead of writting it by code?

Comment: You are correct, I didnt clean up Val. I was dealing with this for 2 hours. I tried a template, but I still cannot get the content of the iframe so I moved on with this method.

Comment: I believe is correct that your iContent doesn't get any value, because is an IFRAME, it only shows another embedded website inside of it.  The "Congratulations... " message is in another HTML page, a page that you don't control

Comment: Also, try to console.log( ) the document.getElementById if it has something at least.... and see if it has innerHTML, innerText, value, etc...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you cannot access the contents of an embedded iFrame since it is a separate document on a separate domain and that violates all the cross-origin protocols.

Comment: Yes, there is a cross-domain issue. I was about to start digging on postMessage but then, the third party website offered us to redirect a successful response to a file on our server, where we have full control, and fixed the issue. I remember I did something with iFrames back in my .NET times together with Javascript and I was able to get the content through .contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML, and I thought it was possible to do this with Angular, but clearly I was wrong and my solution was a decade old. Thank you all for your help.